# how to insert through Multiple Select Statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have the tables:

```
Credit_account
==============

Acid int (PK)(AI) 
Customer Id(Foreign Key ref Customer Table)
Credit Account char(15);
```

I want to insert record as

```
1          2             1-2
2          3             2-3
3          1             1-3
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason why you must use a select statement? Then there is some missing information.

If you have to use a select statement, it could be because the data from this table is from a JOIN. Else, you do not need multiple SELECT statements. An INSERT statement is sufficient.